# How to register new user in PlayFab uinsg REST apis

Tags: flutter, playfab

I am trying to use PlayFab on flutter. Unfortunately there is no PlayFab sdk for flutter.

After looking at REST API, I am confused as to how to use it to authenticate the developer and then create a player account.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/gaming/playfab/api-references/?view=playfab-rest

Whats the best approach to implement this and how can I integrate flutter with playfab